# Laravel - Show data from a specific user

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a listing that will only show lyrics from the logged user, but no succeed. Need help please.

[image]

Sorry for the image link, but my reputation is still low to add images.

As you can see I have two lyrics menus, one is already accessible only for admin users and the other to show the lyrics list for authenticated user.

How can I do that?

**LyricController**

{

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('can:admin-content');
}

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $lyrics = Lyric::orderBy('lyric', 'ASC')->paginate('10');

    return view('admin.lyrics.index', [
        'lyrics' => $lyrics,
    ]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    // load the create form (app/views/lyrics/create.blade.php)
    return view('admin.lyrics.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->only([
        'title',
        // 'artist',
        'info',
        'video_url',
        'lyric'
    ]);

    $data['slug'] = Str::slug($data['title'], '-');

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
        'slug' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', 'unique:lyrics'],
        // 'artist' => ['required', 'string', 'max:200'],
        'info' => ['string', 'max:100'],
        'video_url' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', 'unique:lyrics'],
        'lyric' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->route('lyrics.create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    // $artist = new Singer;
    // $artist->artist = $data['artist'];
    // $artist->save();

    $lyric = new Lyric;
    $lyric->title = trim($data['title']);
    $lyric->slug = $data['slug'];
    $lyric->info = $data['info'];
    $lyric->video_url = $data['video_url'];
    $lyric->lyric = $data['lyric'];
    $lyric->save();

    Session::flash('message', 'Música adicionada com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('lyrics.index');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource
 *
 *
 .
 *
 * @param  \App\Lyric  $lyric
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $lyric = Lyric::find($id);

    return view('admin.lyrics.show', [
        'lyric' => $lyric
    ]);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Lyric  $lyric
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $lyric = Lyric::find($id);

    if ($lyric) {
        return view('admin.lyrics.edit', [
            'lyric' => $lyric
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('lyrics.index');
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Lyric  $lyric
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $lyric = Lyric::find($id);

    if ($lyric) {
        $data = $request->only([
            'title',
            // 'artist',
            'info',
            'video_url',
            'lyric'
        ]);

        if ($lyric['title'] !== $data['title']) {
            $data['slug'] = Str::slug($data['title'], '-');

            $validator = Validator::make($data, [
                'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
                'info' => ['string', 'max:100'],
                'video_url' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', 'url'],
                'slug' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', 'unique:lyrics'],
                'lyric' => ['string'],
            ]);
        } else {
            $validator = Validator::make($data, [
                'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
                'info' => ['string', 'max:100'],
                'video_url' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100', 'url'],
                'lyric' => ['string'],
            ]);
        }

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->route('lyrics.edit', [
                'lyric' => $id
            ])
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        $lyric->title = trim($data['title']);
        $lyric->info = $data['info'];
        $lyric->video_url = $data['video_url'];
        $lyric->lyric = $data['lyric'];

        if (!empty($data['slug'])) {
            $lyric->slug = $data['slug'];
        }

        $lyric->save();
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'Música alterada com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('lyrics.index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Lyric  $lyric
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{

    $lyric = Lyric::find($id);
    $lyric->delete();

    Session::flash('message', 'Música excluída com sucesso!');
    return redirect()->route('lyrics.index');
}
```

Edit: I have just added foreign key to the Users Migration as suggested

**Route: web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'Site\HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('painel')->group(function(){
Route::get('/', 'Admin\HomeController@index')->name('admin');

/* Login Routing */
Route::get('/login', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@index')->name('login'); 
Route::post('/login', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@authenticate');

/* Logout Route */
Route::post('/logout', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
Route::get('/logout', 'Admin\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout-get');

/* Register Routing */
Route::get('/register', 'Admin\Auth\RegisterController@index')->name('register'); 
Route::post('/register', 'Admin\Auth\RegisterController@register');

/* Users Routing */
Route::resource('/users', 'Admin\UserController');

/* Profile Routing */
Route::get('/profile', 'Admin\ProfileController@index')->name('profile');
Route::put('/profilesave', 'Admin\ProfileController@save')->name('profile.save');

/* Lyrics Routing */
Route::resource('/lyrics', 'Admin\LyricController');
});
```

**User.php (model):**

```
public function lyrics()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lyric::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Lyric.php (model):**

```
protected $guarded = ['id', 'singer_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function singer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Singer::class)->withTimestamps();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you could add more details in you question, but let me suggest a scenario to give you an idea of how it might be done:

Assuming you have Passport or JWT for user authentication, and that your user is logged in through api, and that you have 'Lyrics' model with `user_id` foreign key, you can do the following :

```
$logged_user = auth()->guard('api')->user();

if(isset($logged_user)){
    $lyrics = Lyrics::where('user_id',$logged_user->id)->get();
    //do whatever you need with lyrics
}
else{
    // user not authenticated
    return false;
}
```

More on authentication from Laravel documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication)

Comment: I dont know what Passport or JWT is, Im quite new to Laravel. I'll edit my post with the codes.

Comment: I edited the post with the controller and model infos

Answer (score 0):

To show data from a logged in User. You need to establish an eloquent relationship between the User Model and The lyrics model. 
 Then you could just do something like `$user -> lyrics()`